# Javascript mixins in the constructor

Tags: javascript

Okay, I just can't figure this out..

How can I pass an object into a constructor and mix it into that functions prototype?

A very contrived example is as such:

```
// Some base classes

Honda = {
    speed: function(){
        return 60;
    },
    color: function(){
        return red;
    }
}

Ford = {
    speed: function() {
        return 70;
    },
    color: function(){
        return blue;
    }
}

// The class I want to mix them into

Car = function(carType){
    // I want to do something like this!
    _.extend(this.prototype, carType);
}

Car.prototype.describe = function(){
    return this.speed() + this.color();
}

// Then use it as such
ford = new Car(Ford);
honda = new Car(Honda);
etc...
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The prototype is shared by all instances of the constructor function. I.e. when you call `ford = new Car(Ford);`, all existing `Car` instances would have a function `color` that returns blue. After `honda = new Car(Honda);`, all instances (including `ford`) would return red as color. I doubt you want to extend the prototype. Those look rather like instance specific properties and hence should go on the instance. Also note that `this.prototype` doesn't exist, `.prototype` is property of the *constructor function*.

Comment: And even if you'd successfully merge the objects, `this.speed + this.color` won't work because `speed` and `color` are functions.

Comment: ahhh, thanks! with regards to your second comment, that was a typo (fixed).

Comment: I didn't realize the prototype was shared by all instances of a function. I guess I'll figure out a way to add these methods to each instance instead. thanks

Comment: Actually in a OO point of view, "Car" should be the base class, while "Ford" and "Honda" is a sub class. You are thinking them in a wrong way. Seems like you misunderstand the Factory pattern and Class concept in OOP.

Comment: @ChrisLi yes, in this example that's certainly how it should be structured. I think there are a few reasons why I would want to do it differently in my application (although I've been considering otherwise). More over, I was just curious how this could be accomplished for the sake of my never-ending attempt to understand javascript.

Comment: Well, if you just want to extend the instance, it would be `_.extend(this, varType)`. I suggest you also read up on prototype in JavaScript, e.g. on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Comment: If you want to add property in constructor, simply use ```this.xxx = xxx``` or ```_.extend(this, varType)```